# Polipo HTTPS Authentication Problem

Tags: networking, proxy, authentication, polipo

I use internet behind http proxy, and that requires authentication. I tried using polipo to bypass the authenticated proxy to 127.0.0.1:9134.

Applying these settings to my browser, works fine for http://examplewebsite.com

but for https://examplewebsite.com, it asks for authentication. Also my host proxy authentication does not work in the authentication dialog.

Settings I have changed in my /etc/polipo/config

```
proxyPort=9134
parentProxy = "172.31.1.10:8080"
parentAuthCredentials = "username:mypassword"
```

Comment: Did you add the settings in your browser?

Comment: @Jobin yes, i did it for all protocols http, https, ftp & socks. also tried using in google chrome, same problem